# Sharing Data with AppGroup

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I want to share one variable from my UIKit File to my Widget Extension created with SwiftUI.
[I followed this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618123/ios-14-widgets-swiftui-firebase) Please look at the answer from J Arango.

But i dont understand the last part there.
I have to use `import MySharedObjects`.

So I did this:

```
    import MySharedObject

struct testing {
    let mySharedObject = MySharedObject(name: "My Name", lastName: "My Last Name")
                       
     do {
         let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(mySharedObject)
    
          /// Make sure to use your "App Group" container suite name when saving and retrieving the object from UserDefaults
          let container = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.com.widgetTest.widgetContainer")
              container?.setValue(data, forKey: "sharedObject")
                            
          /// Used to let the widget extension to reload the timeline
          WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    
          } catch {
            print("Unable to encode WidgetDay: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }
}
```

But I get the following errors.

- Extra argument at position #1, #2 in call
- Missing argument for parameter from call
- insert from : <#Decoder#>
- expected declaration where I use the `do` part.

Comment: This might help you: [Share data between main App and Widget in SwiftUI for iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922032/share-data-between-main-app-and-widget-in-swiftui-for-ios-14) If it's just one variable you can use shared `UserDefaults`. And why do you need `MySharedObjects`?

Comment: I have to admit that i dont understand what the person is explaining. Is he creating a text file and store the data there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Save data to `UserDefaults` in your main App:

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: <your_app_group>)!.set("test", forKey: "test")
```

2. Read data from `UserDefaults` in your Widget:

```
let testStr = UserDefaults(suiteName: <your_app_group>)!.string(forKey: "test")
```

If you want to save other types see:

- [How can I use UserDefaults in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203241/how-can-i-use-userdefaults-in-swift)

Comment: It worked thank you. It was much more simple than I tought. I tested it with Main app as SwiftUI and Widget as SwiftUI. I will check tomorrow if this also works with my Main app as Storyboard and Widget as SwiftUI.