# Realm sync with swiftUI widget?

Tags: mongodb, swiftui, realm

How we can use realm sync in swiftUI widget?
I used the same method to opening realm from swiftUI app by `flexibleSyncConfiguration` in `getTimeline` function but as user login on the main app it seems it can't find the user on the widget.
Another way i found is using `App Groups` here: [iOS 14 Widgets + SwiftUI + Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618123/ios-14-widgets-swiftui-firebase)
which solution is the right one?

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }

func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    completion(entry)
}

func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
 
    if let user = app.currentUser {
        let config = user.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subs in
            if let _ = subs.first(named: "allTasks") {
                return
            } else {
                subs.append(QuerySubscription<TASK>(name: "allTasks") {
                    $0.owner_id == user.id
                })
            }
        })
        
        
        Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let realm):
                let allTasks = realm.objects(TASK.self)
                
           
                let timelineEntries = allTasks.map { section in
                    SimpleEntry(name: section.name)
                }
                
               
                let timeline = Timeline(entries: Array(timelineEntries), policy: .atEnd)
                completion(timeline)
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to open Realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}

struct taskWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
    Text(entry.date, style: .time)
}
}

struct taskWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "taskWidget"

var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
        taskWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    .description("This is an example widget.")
}
}

struct taskWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        taskWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of approaches from init'ing the widget with Realm, to having your main app observe Realm for changes and write them locally, and have the widget then be notified of those changes. A lot of it depends on if the widget needs real-time updates directly or can it work with existing data. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your help. What i want is widget have real-time updates directly.my problem is i can't find a way to connect realm on main app to widget.

Comment: You can init your widget with realm and it can have it's own observers that receive updates. Alternately, app groups area kind of the easy button see [Configuring App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups?changes=latest_minor)

Comment: @Jay Would you please write a simple code how and where should i init a realm?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `let realm = Realm() ... do stuff with realm` and put it within an `init()` function? (or insert Realm Sync code for Flex Sync with the init)